# Criar um filtro utilizando Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo um filtro em jquery mas estou errando na minha lógica em algum lugar e não estou conseguindo sair do lugar. O meu filtro não está sumindo com algumas palavras que eu digito, ele me traz o bloco inteiro, mesmo a palavra digitada nao estando no item. estou com dificuldades pra resolver.

Esse é o portal : http://www.enap.gov.br/web/pt-br/perguntas-frequentes

Esse é o meu script (só jogar no console da página pra testar)

```
$("input[name='_3_keywords']").keyup(function() {

    var palavrasChave = $("input[name='_3_keywords']").val();
    if (palavrasChave.trim() !== "") {
        var content = document.querySelectorAll('.asset-full-content.show-asset-title');
        content.forEach((element) => {
            element.style.display = 'none';
        });
        $(".taglib-header").hide();
        var $elements = $(".taglib-header:contains(" + palavrasChave + ")");
        $elements.each((index) => {
            $elements[index].nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
        });
        $elements.show();

        var $elementsContent = $(".asset-full-content:contains(" + palavrasChave + ")");
        $elementsContent.each((index) => {
            $($elementsContent[index]).show();
            console.log($($elementsContent[index]).prev());
            $($elementsContent[index]).prev().show(); $elementContent.style.display = 'none';

        });
    } else {
        var elements = $(".taglib-header");
        elements.show();
        elements.each((index) => {
            elements[index].nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá

Creio que foi um simples na hora de definir o último objeto a dar display none

Testa assim

```
 $("input[name='_3_keywords']").keyup(function() {

    var palavrasChave = $("input[name='_3_keywords']").val();
    if (palavrasChave.trim() !== "") {
        var content = document.querySelectorAll('.asset-full-content.show-asset-title');
        content.forEach((element) => {
            element.style.display = 'none';
        });
        $(".taglib-header").hide();
        var $elements = $(".taglib-header:contains(" + palavrasChave + ")");
        $elements.each((index) => {
            $elements[index].nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
        });

        var $elementsContent = $(".asset-full-content:contains(" + palavrasChave + ")");
        $elementsContent.each((index) => {
            $($elementsContent[index]).show();
            $($elementsContent[index]).find(".painel-faq").css( "display", "none");

            var itens = $($elementsContent[index]).find(".painel-faq .panel-title a:contains("+palavrasChave +")");
            itens.each((index) => {
               $(itens[index]).show();
$(itens[index]).parent().parent().parent().css("display","block")
            });

            $($elementsContent[index]).prev().show();  
            $($elementsContent[index]).style.display = 'none';

        });
    } else {
        var elements = $(".taglib-header");
        elements.show();
        elements.each((index) => {
            elements[index].nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
        });
      $('.painel-faq').show();  
    }
});
```

Comment: PauloHDSouza , o problema é que mesmo que eu digite "pesquisa" ele me traz o bloco inteiro. no caso "Bloco de Pesquisa" , nesse bloco o item 6 nao deveria vir na pesquisa, mas ele vem junto com o bloco, mesmo nao tendo nenhum palavra "pesquisa".

Comment: Você  quer que venha O BLOCO com os itens ou só os itens dentro do bloco?

Você está filtrando os itens dentro do bloco ou o bloco?

Comment: A minha lógica era aparecer no caso, apenas os blocos com os itens que contenham a palavra digitada.  Se o bloco tem 10 itens , e apenas 2 tem a palavra pesquisa , o resto ficaria em display:none. ai se o cara apagasse na busca , voltaria tudo.

Comment: Você está filtrando o TITULO do BLOCO, você quer filtrar OS ITENS do bloco? é isso?

Comment: Na verdade teria que ser filtrado os dois. O cara poderia procurar pela palavra do titulo e do bloco.

Comment: Testa e vê se é isso

Comment: Tá faltando pouco, mas fiz vários testes e tá bugando ao fazer a pesquisa. Ex: se vc fizer a pesquisa , ele acha quase todos , mas no último bloco - Casoteca de Gestão Publica, se você digitar "notas" ele não acha. Ainda não entendi o porque.E ao fazer a pesquisa e apagar no campo de busca, o itens não voltam, ficam apenas o itens que você procurou, ou seja , ele não recupera todos itens do bloco após a pesquisa.

Comment: @Thiagolourenço edições que alterem código ou o sentido do post não são recomendadas neste site, sempre opte por informar o autor, por mais que o erro seja explicito.